# Inline CSS override fill field but getting unknown property name

Tags: css, oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Oracle APEX application with an element that i want to change the color of, I'm writing

```
#leg_jet > svg > g > g > g > g > g > path:nth-child(2) {fill="rgb(255,255,255)";}
```

in the page inline CSS field in APEX to change and manipulate the color, except the color is not changing and when inspecting the element I get unknown property name

[image]

so basically i want to override the "fill="rgb(48,159,219)"" of this element with another one.

Note: I can't give the element an ID since APEX doesn't allow me to do so.

I'm ignorant with CSS so any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need to read how to correctly write a CSS declaration .. in the screenshot you added, you can see how to define `fill`

Comment: oh, that helped, thanks a lot <3